# Can struts be configured for serving request from FTP protocol

Tags: servlets, model-view-controller, struts

I was asked this question in an interview. Although I said that this can't be done as struts is only a web framework and basically an extension of the servlets, I wanted to know whether it is really possible to have struts configured for ftp protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entry point in Struts is the [ActionServlet](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/ActionServlet.html), which is a HttpServlet:

> public class ActionServlet extends HttpServlet

From that point onwards it's all HTTP. Struts was built for HTTP, you can't configure it to handle the FTP protocol.

But that's not even [the main problem](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ServletsFaq#otherProtocols), the problem is that the servlet container itself needs to handle FTP and pass the control to the servlet. If you look at the [Servlet API specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) you will see that the focus is on the HTTP(S) protocol. I don't think any servlet container bothered to implement more than that.